# Querying a self referencing junction table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the master table (Table 1) with fields `UI` and `name`

```
-----------------
UI      name
-----------------
T001    Organism
T002    Plant
T004    Fungus
T005    Virus
T007    Bacterium
-----------------
```

and second table (Table 2) with `name1` and `name2` fields

```
---------------------
name1       name2
---------------------
Organism    Organism
Organism    Fungus
Plant       Virus
Virus       Bacterium
Organism    Bacterium
---------------------
```

I need to generate the following output

```
------------
UI1     UI2
------------
T001    T001
T001    T004
T002    T005
T005    T007
T001    T007
------------
```

Here is my initial attempt

```
SELECT * FROM table2 AS t2
JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t2.name1 = t1.name
JOIN table1 AS t3 ON t2.name2 = t3.name;
```

which, unfortunately, returns wrong number of rows. I wonder how to do joins correctly.

Comment: That query seems correct. Please show the output you get and explain how it is wrong

Comment: Do you mean `SELECT t1.UI AS UI1, t3.UI AS UI2 FROM table2 AS t2.....`

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen The output is to long to paste it here.

Comment: @Andrej, the way you have described your tables, table1 is traditionally called a 'master table', while table2 is a design to hold a 'many to many' relation between records of the same table, sometimes called a self referencing junction table, commonly used to represent graphs (trees, lists,  close equivalent to adjacency list of graphs). It may help others if you change the title to something like "Querying a self referencing junction table"

Comment: @MadhavPrabhoo Thanks, I change the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use two aliases on table1:

```
select
    t1a.UI as UI1,
    t1b.UI as UI2
from
    table2 t2,
    table1 t1a,
    table1 t1b
where
    t2.name1 = t1a.name and
    t2.name2 = t1b.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using subquery in `select` statement of table2.

Here is the code:

```
select 
(select UI from table1 t where t.name=t2.name1) AS UI1,
(select UI from table1 t where t.name=t2.name2) AS UI2
from table2 t2
```